# Blackout text for an art project

Tags: html, css, styling

I want to make an interactive blackout poem for a class. [This is a blackout poem btw](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/multimedia/blackout-poetry.html), and I can see when I inspect the element they have a {. blackout editor style. Is this something I can borrow?

I have been through the basic tutorials on W3 Schools for HTML and CSS text and link styling and I can't find anything that works the way I want it to. 
I want to use a standard text and for each word to "blackout" when the user clicks on it and the end result be that the user is just able to see the non-blacked out words onscreen.

Any ideas? TIA, I'm very new to coding.

Comment: I think some people can help you if you provide some html and css you have worked on.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Such as the HTML and CSS in my answer? :)

Comment: @KyleMartin you know, the chances the person will learn something are higher if she makes it herself. Even if it something small and easy to implement! ;-)

Comment: need to post your css code

Comment: Thanks for the catch @AjayPandya, just did that.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov in honor of your point about learning, I have added an explanation of what my example does.  Thanks for the correction-- that's something I probably should have done from the start.

Comment: @KyleMartin good job! however my point was different.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I figured I'd at least do my best with what I already had posted  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Example:**

```
<span>Here </span>
<span>are </span>
<span>some </span>
<span>words </span>
<span>for </span>
<span>a </span>
<span>poem </span>

<script>
    $("span").on("click", function() {
        $(this).css("background", "black");
    }); 
</script>

<style>
    span {
      cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
```

In action: https://jsfiddle.net/kylemartin/f16okqsq/

Granted, my example doesn't have a mechanism to *un-do* the blackout, but that's just as easy as checking the background color of the span and if it's black, then make it not black.

I think this does what you're looking for.  If not, let me know and I can improve it.  It's a little bit ugly, but it achieves the goal.

**What this code does:**

What we do is we put all the words into their own `<span>`s.  We need this so that each word is its own clickable "unit".  Then we create our Javascript click handler that listens for any click on one of the `<span>`s.  When someone clicks on one of the `<span>`s, we change the background color of that `<span>` to black.  I just added the CSS for good measure.  By the way, the CSS `<style>` tag should go in the `<head>` of your HTML file (or in an external stylesheet).

**The issue with this code:**

Obviously, there's one prime issue with this-- you can't "unhighlight" the words.  However, that's as simple as adding an `if` statement in your click handler that checks the background color of the `<span>` that was clicked.  If the `<span>` has no background, then make it black.  If the `<span>` has a black background, remove the background.  I'll let you figure that part out for yourself. :)  (good learning experience)

Comment: thanks, I didn't expect an answer so quickly, least of all one that makes sense to me lol. I didn't even think of the <span > function. I will give that a whirl. thanks again for taking the time!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help!  If I can be of any further assistance just let me know.  I see that you're new to Stack Overflow, so just so you know, it is general practice to mark the answer that worked for you as the accepted answer.  Obviously you don't *have* to do that, but it would be appreciated  :)